# How do you create a cube mapping skybox image?

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, panorama

I'm wondering which Stackexchange sub section this will be moved to, if this isn't the right place. But how do you create those 3D VR images you see on facebook and all that?

I have [SpaceEngine](http://en.spaceengine.org/) and a tool in it, is to create skybox images.

So if I take the 6 fold images it snaps, and place it into a program can I create the cube map?

I've heard mettle is a program you can use, but that's expensive. Are there free programs to create skybox images?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to take several images with enough overlap, in all angles, probably using a panorama head, (or using a 360° camera)

Then stitch this into a 360 projection with Hugin, and then convert this projection to a cubic one.

Take a look at this: https://hugin.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/Cubic_Projection.html

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly free skybox generator software is rare. A web search "skybox generator" found 2 generators for space skyboxes. Not found one for terrestial sky.

Check these if you are not afraid to run experimental softmare.

http://alexcpeterson.com/spacescape/

https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/3ys4vg/a_month_ago_i_released_a_free_space_skybox/

For your own skyboxes, manual work is still an option. Fill the seams at first, expand to the middle of squares.